# Cubic Spline method for extrapolation in MatLab

Tags: matlab, cubic-spline

I'm trying to predict the value at the next time step of a sinusoidal waveform. For that I'm using Cubic spline extrapolation which I found in this web page.

```
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicSpline.html
```

The following is the Matlab code I used.

```
clear all;close all
 V0_mag=230*sqrt(2/3);
 t1=0;dt=50e-6;
 h=dt;
 H=[4 1 0;1 4 1;0 4 1];
 invH=inv(H);
 Y = zeros(3,1);
 w0=2*pi*60;a=0;b=0;c=0;d=0;
 t=1;
for m=1:0.2/dt
    t11(m)=t1;
    y(m,1)=V0_mag*(1-exp(-20*t11(m)))*sin(w0*t11(m));
    %Cubic splines method for n=3
    if m>5
        Y(3,1)=3*(y(m-2)-y(m-3));
    end
    if m>4
        Y(3,1)=3*(y(m-1)-y(m-2));
    end
    if m>3
        Y(3,1)=3*(y(m)-y(m-1));
    end
    D=(invH*Y);
    ax(m)=a;
    if m>1
        a=y(m-1);b=D(2);
        c=3*(y(m)-y(m-1))-(2*D(2)+D(3));
        d=2*(-y(m)+y(m-1))+D(2)+D(3);
    end
    prey1(m,1)=d*(t)^3+c*(t)^2+b*(t)+a;
    t1=t1+dt;
end

figure(1)
plot(t11,prey1)
hold on
plot(t11,y,'r')
legend
```

This code works for `0<t<1`(interpolation). However for extrapolate I have to make t>1. And when I put t=2 (That means I'm trying to find the value at the next time step) the waveforms does not match. Can anybody help me how to do extrapolation using this code.

Comment: Why are you not using the extrapolate function in matlab?

Comment: I don't think you can use spline for waveform extrapolation (you can't extrapolate far ahead at least). I am not a mathematician, so take my comment with cautious.

Comment: you might want to check out the [interp1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) function. it has a `pchip` method that supports extrapolation

Comment: I need to come up with my own code for this. So I cant use any built in functions.

Comment: Cubic splines only work for interpolation. If you are trying to interpolate at a point `x'`, the spline routine looks at one or several known points on either side of `x'`. If you are trying to extrapolate, you only have points on one side. If you are trying to predict the next value of a sinusoidal waveform though, you could use the periodicity of the waveform to turn the problem into an interpolation problem.

Comment: But there is a function in MatLab that do extrapolation using Cubic Splines.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spline.html